# Unable to connect to posgres using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a postgres instance inside a kubernetes cluster. I have setup a port forward and if I use the postgres CLI I can connect and perform queries as expected.

If I connect via pgadmin it appears to work as expected I am able to see the schemas and navigate to the tbles, but if I attempt to open the query tool I receive the following error:

```
could not send data to server: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057) could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
```

Does anyone know what I need to configure to allow pgadmin to connect to this system?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I couldn't get it to work when running PG from a docker container on my windows machine. So i uninstalled and moved onto HeidiSQL. I would have stayed if PgAdmin would let me roll back to 4.10 which didn't have this issue. However, when i tried it stopped opening altogether until I reinstalled 4.14.

Comment: Sadly not, as I only need to connect intermittently I just use the CLI.

Comment: Do you still have this problem ?
What is your `Host name / address` configured in pgAdmin ?

Comment: @AndrewGill please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that it would be helpful for other community members for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the error message you get isn't very specific. You may need to configure additional access in `pg_hba.conf` file which controls client authentication in **PostgreSQL**. Check its current content and if needed, add the corresponding entry according to [this article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: Just getting hit with this myself.
The pg_hba is correct, it does allow the users from the localhost to connect, even turned off ssl with the same error (excluding the SSL negotiations part)
The "problem" seems to be the port forwaring (in my case using BitVise Tunnelier) that fails the test of time...